# Redirect to the POST form page

Tags: python, django, web-applications, web

I'm developing an application using Django. The main page contains a textarea input where you must enter a list of IDs(this list can be large, so I submit the form using POST). After submiting the form, the server will render a page with a table where you can find informations about every ID. If you click on an ID, you will go to a page where you can modify some fields. For saving the modified fields into the database, the form action is: 'manage_ids/<>/save' and on the server I have a view for this url. How can I redirect the user back to the page with the table? I'm submiting the form using POST so a simple redirect wouldn't work. Or, to remain on the page where you can modify the fields(in this case, if you press the 'Back' browser button, to be redirected to the table page).

Workflow:

```
/ 
POST
/manage_ids
GET
/manage_ids/<<md5>>
POST(save)
/manage_ids/<<md5>>/save

Now, I should be redirected to: 
/manage_ids
```

Comment: "I'm submiting the form using POST so a simple redirect wouldn't work" - er, why not?

Comment: Because I'm submiting the form that gets the data asociated with the textarea input and renders the table page, using POST method. So how this redirect will be? "return redirect('/manage_ids/')"? How it should know what data was in the textarea input?

Comment: redirect makes GET on the url; I need POST or a method to go back two pages(first-the page with the fields and save button--second-the page with the table);

Answer (score 1):

If you need to preserve a long list of IDs across multiple page requests, you should use the [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/sessions/).

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to recommend you take a look at [Django Form wizards](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/)